# Need help converting my PHP application to Coldfusion. Can anyone assist

Tags: php, coldfusion

This is the current PHP, not sure how to begin to convert to Coldfusion.  I need to post this on my coldfusion server.

```
<?php
/**
 * Saves POST input as an XML file and returns a JSON response
 */

$xmlString;

if (isset($_POST['xmlString'])){
$filename  = $_POST['xmlFilename'];
$xmlString = stripslashes($_POST['xmlString']);

$newFile = "_data/".$filename.".edit.xml";

//write new data to the file, along with the old data 
$handle = fopen("../".$newFile, "w"); 
if (fwrite($handle, $xmlString) === false) { 
    echo "{error:\"Couldn't write to file.\"}";  
} 
else {
    //echo "{filename:\"".$newFile."\"}";
    echo "success:::$newFile:::$xmlString";
}
    fclose($handle);    
}
?>
`
```

Comment: There is nothing vague or too broad about this question. Give the new guy a chance here folks! @kingjtiv - From the comments, the snippet receives two `FORM` variables, a file name and xml string. Then saves the xml to a file on the server. Then outputs the result on screen. Simple stuff in CF. Start by looking up some of the functions in the php manual [`isset`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), [`stripslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php), ... and convert them to the CF equivalents. Take a stab at it and post back if you run into specific problems.

Comment: Kingjtv. As Leigh said. Post any issues here and I will try and help out as well.  Or shoot me an email at jason(at)assetmedia.com.au and I'd be happy to get you going. Jason.

Comment: Just to add to the sentiment that this is a perfectly valid question, and should be reopened. Is the question ambiguous? No. Is it vague? No. Is it incomplete? No. Is it overly broad? No. Is it rhetorical? No. It is a question, and it's a very reasonable question. What is wrong with you, John, jeroen, Blorgbeard, paislee, Jack? Is it possible to downvote the "moderators" on S/O?

Comment: I've answered the original question here: http://bit.ly/SyixPJ. I've used a link shortener because that URL will possibly have more longevity than the URL the blog post is at, so makes sense in this situation. Plus the title (and accordingly the URL) of the blog article is unflattering to the people who closed this question, so is unhelpful to be posted in full here.

Comment: flagged for moderator attention to re-open.

Comment: The closers should have provided a better explanation in the comments. However, I suspect that the question was closed because it shows neither a good-faith effort to solve the problem nor an attempt to learn--this looks like @kingjtiv simply dumping his(her?) work on the Internet and hoping that nice people will do it for him. The social norm of this community expects a modicum of an effort to solve it on your own or to ask a more specific, detailed question that can help you solve it on your own--this is not a place for unqualified programmers to get other people to do their job for them.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky. Thanks. Yeah, I think the challenge here is that the window from "open" to "close" is quite narrow (perhaps it could be a coupla days, with a warning displayed front and centre?), and the people closing it have not attempted to remedy the situation at all, so they are actually being as unhelpful to the situation as the originator is, in a way. I know S/O needs rules, but the bottom line is we're here to help, not slavishly follow rules. My approach would have been to suggest to the person how they could improve, and then give them a chance to do so (I'm gonna have to continue...)

Comment: @JoelSpolsky [cont'ed]. Also in this case the people closing the question didn't even seem to be `ColdFusion` people, so in a way... who are they to be part of this decision anyhow? That said, I dunno how you could work this. Perhaps a person needs to have a certain rep on all the tags against a question before they can act as cop? Dunno. You'd know better than me.  Thanks for pitching in here, btw.  It's much appreciated. I'll post my answer now!

Comment: You don't always need to be an [CF] developer to identify a bad [CF] question, but weighting still sounds an interesting idea. Something like if you have >X rep in an involved tag, you contribute more than the current 20% to a vote, if you have <200 rep in all involved tags, you contribute less than 20% to a vote? Will go look if this has been raised on Meta before, or do so if not...

Comment: "Convert my code in X to Y" questions are generally considered off-topic. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54345/please-convert-my-code-to-x-questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know PHP very well, but I can infer stuff and I can google stuff. If I get stuff wrong, can someone please correct me.

- [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): whilst not a direct analogy, one should use [structKeyExists()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbb.html) to do variable checking like this. `isset()` is mostly directly equivalent to [isDefined()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbd.html), but one should avoid `isDefined()` if possible due to its propensity for returning false positives;
- [$_POST variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) are the same as FORM-scoped variables;
- [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) unescapes the backslashes that escape quotes within a string;
- `.` (dot) is the [string-concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), like `&` in CFML;
- [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) opens a file, and the "w" argument opens it for writing. So like the equivalent usage of [fileOpen()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d9c.html) in CFML.
- [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) writes to said file.
- `=== false` bit checks to see if there was a file-write error, which has no direct equivalent in, CFML, so I guess the analogy would be to put a try/catch around the file ops (which one should always do anyhow).
- [echo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is the equivalent of [writeOutput()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6da1.html) (or just <cfoutput>);
- [fclose()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) is the same as [fileClose()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6da1.html).

That's about it: I think the rest of it is self-explanatory.

One thing I will say is that it was pretty easy to (correctly ~) guess all this stuff, or google it.  I just googled "php fopen", "php dot operator" etc (mostly to just get the link to the docs). So you could perhaps have done this yourself.

Comment: Adam, you have a typo - "stripshashes" should be "stripslashes." It won't let me edit because edits have to be at least six characters.

Comment: fixed (more characters because SO hates brevity)

Comment: @Peter I specifically did NOT want to recommend isDefined() as it's flaky, so I have reworded your edit to make both yours and my intent more clear. Cheers though.